# Delete Mac partition and grow Ext4 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac

I have a 2015 non-retina Macbook pro with a dual boot Mac-Kubuntu 18.04. I installed initially Mac Mojave (APFS File system), then rEFInd from there and finally Kubuntu. This is how the layout looks like:

[image]

Basically, I would like to delete partition number 2 (MAC apfs) and grow the existing Kubuntu partiton (number3) so that it takes the whole space.Is there a fairly safe way of doing this? This is a more detailed view of the partition layout:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do not know Mac, but saw some comment that there is some maintenance on Mac that can only be done from Mac's software.

Comment: If that is the case, then what would be the best way to shrink the mac apfs partition to a minimum (say 20Gb) and extend the Ext4 partiton?

Comment: On PC we use gparted from live installer. Not sure but very new Mac needs kernel patch for NVMe SSDs and still not 100%. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MacBook-Finally-Linux-SSD-RW